# any support for UNDO in Sqlite manager

Tags: sqlite, sqlitemanager

due to my impatience i corrupted my database with a replace query now all rows in that column shows 0. 
is there any support for Sqlite manager in Firefox using which i will be able to undo to my previous state of DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as UNDO -- however if you began a transaction prior to starting your query (or queries), you could simple not commit the transaction. Short of that, you need to restore from a backup (and if you don't have a backup, you'll probably think to make one next time?).